# What is happening to my snapping? AKA Snap vertex to vertex in object mode

Tags: snapping

I've seen many threads covering the topic. But I'd like a simple and straight answer. Is there, in Blender, a way to drag and snap a vertex to the position of vertex in object mode? It's very easy and works properly in edit mode, so why not in object mode?! Also why the vertex snapping in object mode behaves like is pushing away instead of moving together?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QstSx.jpg

[image]

Comment: Can you lease attach your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? I made exatly the same scene with the same snapping settings and it works for me OK...

Comment: This is the file. Maybe is something related to the user preference?
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3910" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3910/)

Comment: Thats weird, the snapping works for me even directly in your .blend. I would try File -> Load Factory Settings, otherwise I have no idea :/

Comment: Nothing, tried resetting and got the same result... I'll try reinstalling now.

Comment: Tried reinstalling. Nothing changed, they snap far from each other.

Comment: Can you please try slightly your scene with different snapping settings? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3911

Comment: Works only with the vertex where the origin has been moved to. Which takes too much time to set up. Has I said in my first post, I'd like it to work as in edit mode. Closest vertex to the mouse cursor position gets snapped to a second vertex, where the cursor moves to.

Comment: It won't work like in Edit mode. In Object mode snapping works by object bounding box (enable in Object tab in properties panel to visualize). In Edit mode - by geometry. I don't get behaviour from the shown gif, but cylinder will snap in ~ 1 Blender Unit from snapping target in this case as it's how bounding boxes are touching

Comment: Bounding box snapping and ~ 1 unit distance make no sense in a snapping system. If you have to leave behind and reset the position of your pivot every time you snap an object to another, I can see now why professionals won't bother modeling in Blender... :(

Comment: You don't have to reset position of pivot. Snap object in Edit mode by entering Edit mode and using snap on desired element of geometry and hovering mouse over snapping target. It's your choice to choose whatever to use; for Blender try Sverchok or Animation nodes addons to model with more precision with node modeling system

Comment: So how do you move the pivot and the vertices together in edit mode? Installing a node base system to do these kind of basic operations is out of the question.